# POST request to REST API on Android not getting parameters

Tags: android, django, rest, post, django-rest-framework

I'm building a webapp with an associated REST API in the backend.

The API made with django-rest-framework is working, I can do the following from the command line:

```
$ http http://localhost:8000/API/api-token-auth/ username=ortho1 password=123456

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 11 May 2016 12:43:05 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.5.1+
Vary: Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

{
    "token": "4d6e32726e321448fc212242fc03a3fa84c80510"
}
```

But from my Android App I try to do the following:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    // Starting the request
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {

        url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8000/API/api-token-auth/");
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

             /* optional request header */
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            /* for GET request */
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        String urlParameters =
                "username=" + URLEncoder.encode("ortho1", "UTF-8") +
                        "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode("123456", "UTF-8");

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" +
                Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));

        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                urlConnection.getOutputStream ());
        wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
        wr.flush ();
        wr.close ();

        InputStream inputStream;
        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) { // 2xx code means success
            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        } else {

            inputStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();

        }

        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);


        String response = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);

        Log.i("Request", response);

        return response;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    } finally {
        if(urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }

}

private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    String line = "";
    String result = "";

    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        result += line;
    }

        /* Close Stream */
    if(null!=inputStream){
        inputStream.close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

I get in the console as response from the server:

```
{"detail":"JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"}
```

as result.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You are not sending "token".

Comment: Token is in the response, not in the request in the first example.

Comment: Ok. `$ http http://localhost:8000/API/api-token-auth/ username=ortho1 password=123456`. I don't know django but why would that be a POST? For me it looks more like a GET.

Comment: `/* for Get request */
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST"); ` ??? Well that is wrong.

Comment: it's not a Get, it's the format of httpie. I can make it explicit:

http -f POST http://localhost:8000/API/api-token-auth/ username=ortho1 password=123456
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 11 May 2016 13:43:17 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.5.1+
Vary: Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

{
    "token": "4d6e32726e321448fc212242fc03a3fa84c80510"
}

Comment: @greenapps that's just a comment, i'll change it.

Comment: `{"detail":"JSON parse error`. You are not sending JSON to begin with. So if your server tries to parse json text you can expect such. But then i dont understand why using console its ok.

Comment: Is your parse error printed by `Log.i("Request", response);` ?

Comment: `wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);` Do you know how much bytes will be send? Does it match with the preceding content length `Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length)` ? Try with `wr.write(urlParameters.getBytes());`

Comment: `urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");`. Where in your console command are you stating that json has to be send? Is django expecting json? Django send json yes. Change to form url encoded instead.

Comment: I removed the content-type header and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove this line,

urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

---

For your info, the best library for dealing with any **REST API** is the **RETROFIT** 
http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 0):

(Wild guess here)

I see that your server is running in localhost and you're trying to access it using the IP... that won't work. If you're testing locally try running the server in the broadcast ip: 

`$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

or if you need a public address you can use some service like `ngrok` to route your requests to a local server

Comment: My tests were made using 
pyon manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000, the IP I use is the host from the Android Emulator.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");.
```

Where in your console command are you stating that json has to be send? Is django expecting json? Django send json yes. Change to form url encoded instead